# Retrieving the month from the timestamp format "25/Nov/2016:15:48:01 +0000'

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm currently working with Hive SQL and I have the '`timestamp`' column in a table with the format `"25/Nov/2016:15:48:01 +0000"`.

How can I extract the month which is 'Nov' from the above format without using SUBSTRING() function.

I tried,

```
SELECT MONTH(timestamp) FROM table_name;
```

But it returned as null. What should be the correct way to retrieve the month which is 'Nov' from the above timestamp format.

Comment: Is the column defined as a TIMESTAMP or just a string? If it's a string you should use SUBSTRING.

Comment: can you check below way!

Comment: Do you have an example for February and/or December, just to check that the label is in English and not in French (FEV) or German (DEZ) or whatever? That would play hell with Java string formats, if you can't specify the locale...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the below [example](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF)..

- `unix_timestamp(time,'dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss')` and then try your month function

  OR
- First convert your timestamp to string to apply month function below like this 
  example

> string `from_unixtime(bigint unixtime[, string format])` Converts the
>   number of seconds from unix epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC) to a
>   string representing the timestamp of that moment in the current system
>   time zone in the format of "1970-01-01 00:00:00"

then you can apply month function which will return month int format which can be converted equivalent String later

> int   `month(string date)`   Returns the month part of a date or a
>   timestamp string: month("1970-11-01 00:00:00") = 11,
>   month("1970-11-01") = 11.

Comment: Your feedback was really useful Ram. I've used MONTH(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(timestamp,'dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss'))) and it returned me the month in int format easily.